# How to capture error messages thrown by a command?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script where in I need to capture the error message that it's throwing. Note: according to PowerShell, there is no error and command is executed successfully.

For example: I tried to download a package from SVN Link. The Link actually is not present. The script is showing me error message on the console. However, when I tried to check `$_` or `$?` or `$error`, I did not see any error message. However, `$LASTEXITCODE` returned value 1. I need to get the exact error message.

Comment: `$error[0]` would give you the last error message encountered.

Comment: What are code that you are using to perform the download? Are you invoking an external tool or using a cmdlet?

Comment: Hi Mike, I am using the command - svn --force export $SVN .

Comment: `$error[0] | select *` gives the full list of exceptions from the latest to the oldest in the console.
You can also running `get-Error` , which will work from PowerShell 6.0 and above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you get an error message, you need to capture the error stream:

```
$msg = command 2>&1
```

or

```
command 2>error.txt
```

PowerShell writes its messages to different streams that can be redirected to files for capturing the respective output.

- Stream 1 (default): regular output ("STDOUT")
- Stream 2: error messages ("STDERR"), including error messages from external programs
- Stream 3: warning messages
- Stream 4: verbose messages
- Stream 5: debug messages
- Stream 6: information messages *(only PowerShell v5 and newer)*

To capture a particular stream in a file you need to redirect the stream number to a file name. For instance

```
command 2>"C:\path\to\error.log"
```

would capture all error messages produced by `command` in the file `C:\path\to\error.log`. Use `2>>` instead of `2>` if you want to append to the file instead of overwriting it with each run.

You can also combine other streams with STDOUT to process/redirect all command output:

```
command >>"C:\path\to\all.log" *>&1
```

See [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) or [this Scripting Guy article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) for more information about streams and redirection.

Things worth of note:

- The `*>` redirection was introduced with PowerShell v3, hence it won't work in PowerShell v2 and earlier.
- PowerShell v5 introduced a new stream ([Information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/07/04/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/), stream number 6) since people kept misusing `Write-Host` because they didn't understand what the cmdlet was intended for.

Comment: what if i have to capture the output as well as the error message?

Comment: For ex $Output=$SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar(). This command is supposed to return no of rows to me. However, I also need to see if it throws any error. How can I accomodate the same in this case?

Comment: That's a different beast. If that command throws an error, it should be put into the `$error` special variable, so you should be able to access the message via `$error[0]`, as @devnull mentioned in the first comment to your question.

Comment: this worked best for me: `PS C:\temp> .\testEmailSMTP.ps1 >>"EmailTest.txt" *>&1`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your executable is named svn.exe and is on the path, you can capture the messages it sends to console this way:

```
$msg = [string] (svn.exe <your parameters here>)
```

You can then parse the $msg string to find information you need.

Comment: Hi David, I am using this command svn --force export $SVN . I tried as you suggested but nothing is being captured in the string.

Comment: Error messages are written to the error stream, not to the default stream, so you need `$msg = svn ... 2>&1` for capturing them. Parentheses and casting the message to a string (`[string](...)`) is not required, though.

Comment: Not only is casting to a string not required, but probably undesirable. The error message might still be in an ErrorRecord object type, in which case, you probably want to keep that rather than convert it to string. That could help you separate the error from stdout after this has been assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [David Brabants answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420673/5185376), you can combine both stdout and stderr into one string array using this command:

```
$output = [string[]] (.\Cli.exe -p $param 2>&1)
```

It will execute `Cli.exe` with the parameter `p`. This is optionally.

## Clarification

`2>&1` means the stream #2 (*stderr*) will be redirected to stream #1 (*stdout*), thus both streams will arrive in `$output`.