# Try/Catch aws cli errors in powershell script

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

I'm trying to have a script automatically create ECR repos for projects as part of the pipeline. I want to check if it already exists first, however `describe-repositories` returns an error instead of "nothing", and it's not caught in a try/catch .

```
try{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "some-project"
}
catch {
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "some-project"    
}
```

Output:

```
An error occurred (RepositoryNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeRepositories operation: The repository with name '...' does not exist in the registry with id '...'
```

Is there a way to capture the error?
Edit: Setting $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" doesn't change behaviour.

Comment: You don't show it so we don't know if you have set ErrorAction to Stop which is necessary for Try/Catch to work. Either set the preference or add to Try command if supported.

Comment: Only terminating errors are cought by try/catch. If your error is not terminating the execution it's a non terminating error. What happens to those is set by the `$ErrorActionPreference` as @RetiredGeek pointed out. See [about_try_catch_finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: I have tried setting $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" before the first aws command, but it did not trigger the catch either.

Comment: `if($(aws ecr describe-...) -match 'RepositoryNotFoundException'){ aws ecr create-... }`

Comment: `throw` the error into catch block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to leverage [**`$LastExitCode`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#lastexitcode) to tell that an error has occurred (Some [minimal AWS CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-returncodes.html#powershell) on this)

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "some-project"

if ($LastExitCode) {
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "some-project"
}
```

If you want the actual error message, you should be able to leverage redirection as described in [How to capture error messages thrown by a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420474/how-to-capture-error-messages-thrown-by-a-command)

---

Really though I think there are two other improvements you can do here:

- Instead of describing a specific repository, [list them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-repositories.html#examples) and see if the one you want exists:

```
$repositories = (aws ecr describe-repositories) | ConvertFrom-Json

if ("some-project" -notin $repositories.repositories.repositoryName) {
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "some-project"
}
```

- If it's an option, use [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)... so you can use [Get-ECRRepository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-ECRRepository.html) and things like `$ErrorActionPreference` work.