# Unable to store Azure CLI error output to a variable

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I tried to make some changes to Azure existing environment using Azure CLI. For success requests I am able to pull the required details using "--query", but for failed request I am not able to capture the output to variable.

Eg:
`az group show -n "rgname"`

output: **(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'rgname' could not be found**

How to capture this **error output to a variable**.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell write the messages to different streams that you can redirect e. g. to the standard output stream:

```
$output = (az group show -n "rgname" 2>&1)
```

Now `$output` will contain both - error messages and the regular output.

Alternative, you could redirect error messages to a file:

```
az group show -n "rgname" 2>error.log
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17421207/1163423

Answer (score 1):

When a program is executed, three file handles are opened in this order: **stdin**, **stdout** and **stderr**. These file handles have numbers: 0, 1 and 2. This will help explain what 2>&1 does (redirects stderr to stdin).

Most programs, but not all, write error messages to stderr.

To capture **stderr** to a variable:

```
error=$(myprogram 2>&1 > /dev/null)
```

That example first redirects **stdout** to /dev/null and then redirects **stderr** to **stdout**. That output is then captured in the variable **error**.

If you also want to capture normal **stdout** messages:

```
error=$({myprogram > tmpfile;} 2>&1)
messages=$(<tmpfile)
rm tmpfile
```